# CSS to fit sidebar under topbar

Tags: html, css

I need to create an empty topbar and an empty sidebar as below. I want to stack them neatly so that the top of the sidebar touches the bottom of the topbar. For that, I am using percentage. However, I just can't get them to do that.

I saw some other threads suggesting to set `html` and `body` with `height: 100%;` and `width : 100%`. But in my app, the layout below is not in the main html document.

```css
#nav-bar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 10%;
    width: 100%;
}

#side-bar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #011a21;
    height: 90%;
    width: 7.5%;
    /*margin-top: 10%;*/
}
```

```html
<div id="nav-bar">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="side-bar"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `#nav-bar` has a `height: 10%`, and you can set the same value for the `top` rule, selector `#side-bar`.

```css
#nav-bar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 10%;
    width: 100%;
}

#side-bar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #011a21;
    height: 90%;
    width: 7.5%;
    /*margin-top: 10%;*/
}
```

```html
<div id="nav-bar">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="side-bar"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I tend to use flex box for this, Maybe grid would be smarter though. I took also care of some scrolling things. Using min with and height 0 on flex parents is key for that.

```css
body,
section {
  min-height: 0;
  min-width: 0;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

nav {
  height: 2rem;
  background: green;
}

section {
  flex: 1 1 0%;
  display: flex;
}

aside {
  width: 4rem;
  background: blue;
  height: 100%;
}

main {
  background: pink;
  flex: 1 1 0%;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 1rem;
}

div {
  border: 1px black dashed;
  height: 300%;
}
```

```html
<nav></nav>
<section>
  <aside></aside>
  <main>
    <div>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum, tempora. Voluptates, iure quis enim hic eius ullam sequi suscipit maiores, eum consectetur nesciunt quae dolorum! Voluptate adipisci praesentium illum dolorem.
      <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum, tempora. Voluptates, iure quis enim hic eius ullam sequi suscipit maiores, eum consectetur nesciunt quae dolorum! Voluptate adipisci praesentium illum dolorem.
      <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum, tempora. Voluptates, iure quis enim hic eius ullam sequi suscipit maiores, eum consectetur nesciunt quae dolorum! Voluptate adipisci praesentium illum dolorem.
      <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum, tempora. Voluptates, iure quis enim hic eius ullam sequi suscipit maiores, eum consectetur nesciunt quae dolorum! Voluptate adipisci praesentium illum dolorem.
      <br>
    </div>
  </main>
</section>
```